# Derivates from a class instance in TF1

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I am using the Physics Informed Neural Networks (PINNs) methodology to solve  non-linear PDEs in high dimension. Specifically, I am using this class https://github.com/maziarraissi/PINNs/blob/master/appendix/continuous_time_inference%20(Burgers)/Burgers.py

where the function `def net_f(self, x,t):` is modified to include more variables than just `x` and `t` i.e. `def net_f(self, w, z, v, t):`

I have two PDEs and a policy function (each an instance of the `PhysicsInformedNN` class) and at some point I have a function which combines the approximation from `def net_f(self, w,z,v,t):` let's say in the following way `y = PDE1(w,z,v,t) + PDE2(w,z,v,t) + policy(w,z,v,t)`. I want to take derivatives of this function with respect to `w,z` and `v`. However, I can't figure out how to do that in `TensorFlow 1.15.2`. This is more or less trivial to do in `TF2` but I want to stick to `TensorFlow 1.15.2` for several reasons.

Basically, the problem boils down to this: from an instantiated model

`model = PhysicsInformedNN(X_u_train, u_train, X_f_train, layers, lb, ub, nu)`

take a derivative of `model.net_u(x,t)` with respect to `x` or `t`. Assuming, either the model is trained or not trained. If I can do that then I can figure out how to take derivatives of function `y` above w.r.t. the variables in each PDE and the policy.

Note: This can be done fully analytically, i.e. I can hard code the formulas for the derivatives of `y` using values from `model.predict()` (which would be `numpy` arrays). I can check that the derivative formulas are correct with `TF2` I just want to use automatic differentiation to do this (since the formulas are complicated and become very cumbersome as the dimension of the PDEs increases).

Comment: In the same code, [here](https://github.com/maziarraissi/PINNs/blob/0542794b0a91b9e8764a38f5fc9cd9647a3929ba/appendix/continuous_time_inference%20(Burgers)/Burgers.py#L108) the author has implemented the PDE loss using autograd· What is the problem?

Comment: @PrakharSharma I ended up coding everything from scratch in TF 2.0 to avoid using sessions. The problem is that in TF 1.0 when they are outside of their sessions I could not figure out how to use the trained neural nets (NNs) to take derivatives of objects which are functions of the the same NNs. In TF 2.0 this is very easy to do.

Comment: Yes, TF 1.0 was very difficult to learn. TF 2.0 is no better for me. PyTorch is way simpler. You can also try `tf.Keras`.